# Syntax for Branching SQL Query Based on a Parameter

Tags: mysql

I would love to do a MySQL query like this. I know the syntax is incorrect and I can't use an "if" at the beginning of a query like this. This is for Tableau custom SQL query, by the way. I'd like to have a negative value for AccountID mean displaying all Accounts, and a positive value mean displaying either the account associated with the positive value, or displaying nothing if there is no account associated with the positive value.

```
if <Parameters.AccID> < 0
    select * from Accounts
else
    select * from Accounts where id = <Parameters.AccID>
```

Can someone help me do this with correct syntax?
Since I must use Tableau Desktop as the platform for this, I only have access to query syntax.

Comment: Why do you want to do it _in SQL_ rather than in your programming language?

Comment: Because this is taking place inside Tableau Desktop, I don't have access to programming logic inside Tableau Desktop except for custom SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can run such a multi query, if you need it.

```
SELECT if (Parameters.AccID < 0, @q := 'select * from Accounts',@q := CONCAT('select * from Accounts where id = ',Parameters.AccID));
 PREPARE stmt from @q;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
```

Comment: I appreciate the thought you put into this, I would +1 if I had enough rep, but that would work for me within MySQL, but not on Tableau desktop which is the platform I must use. This isn't your fault at all. I will see if I can edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: i doubt thta will work with Mysql have yo a chance to switch to sql SERVER, where cann use stored procedures with similar functionality https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_stored_procedures.htmw